# Applescript - Can't access variable inside objet depending of app

Tags: applescript

I have a script where I'm trying to access the "duration" value of an activity, inside an array of activities. The *activities* array comes from decoded JSON data:

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
  repeat with activity in activities
    log activity of activity
    log duration of activity
  end repeat
end tell
```

There is no error when using this code inside a `tell application "Finder"` block, but when I use this inside a `tell application "Numbers"` block, I get a compiler error which says that it can't get `duration of activity` because of an access denied.
Why is this working with Finder but not with Numbers ?

Comment: What is `activities`? Basically the application dictionary must contain the property/command and the FourChar code must match. Nevertheless there is no `duration` property in `Finder` anyway.

Comment: I edited my question; this is an array of objects that I get from another app.

Comment: If the code is not related to a specific app don't put it into an application tell block.

Comment: But I need to access these variables inside a tell Numbers block in order to populate tables with this data.

Comment: You have to put it out. `Numbers` has a `duration` keyword which doesn't match the `duration` keyword of the *another app*. This causes the error.

Comment: Okay, I understand! Is there a way to modify the keys of an object ? Or to copy it with different keys ?

Comment: You can do `repeat with activity in activities` `set theDuration to duration of activity` `tell application...` or use a handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try this.

Comment: I'd change the name of your variable: e.g., `repeat with an_activity in activities`. Naming your variable with the same name as a record label is bad practice, and it might be confusing Numbers.